# Exploring locations in Pathfinder

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

In [PathFinder: Rise of the Runelords](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/adventureCardGame/riseOfTheRunelords), how many times can you explore a location? I can discard a BotG to explore:

[image]

Can I explore as many times as I want in my turn? Imagine I start with 3 BotG, a weapon and a Cure spell:

[image]

Can I explore, then discard a BotG and explore, then discard and explore, then discard and explore, THEN play the Cure, target myself, shuffle all the blessings into my deck, and end the turn by drawing all cards until I have 5 again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes and No

According to page 8 of the [Rise of the Runelords rule book](http://paizo.com/download/pathfinder/PZO6000-Rulebook.zip), you start your turn with 1 free 'explore' action (which must be your first explore), and you can discard certain cards from your hand to gain additional explore actions with no limit (other than what's in your hand).

But I think you misunderstand how Cure works:

The cards are moved from the Discard pile back into the Deck (not to your Hand), so without a mechanism to draw additional cards, its nearly impossible to reuse the same blessings in the same turn.

Comment: I linked the wrong spell, was going for regular `Cure`. Fixed

Comment: "If, during a single exploration, multiple effects
each give you an additional exploration, it counts as a total of 1 more
exploration, not a series of additional explorations." Why doesn't this stop me from exploring several times with BotG?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Because you would discard a BotG to gain an exploration and resolve that exploration; then separately, you would discard another BotG to gain a different exploration and resolve that exploration as well. The ruling is there because of several cards that can grant you an exploration as a result of encountering them (e.g. "...discard this card and immediately explore again"): if you somehow encountered two of these at the same time, they'd only grant you 1 additional exploration, since they both occurred during the same initial exploration.